# Updating View from within a Socket.IO thread

Tags: java, android, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I think it's time for a question for my stackoverbros. I'm using socket.io-client.java https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java to communicate with my node server using socket.io. So far the connection works fine.

Here's onCreate and variable definitions.

```
    class Text
{
    String username;
    String message;
}

Socket socket;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<Text> texts = new ArrayList<Text>();
String username = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    initList();
    activateEnter();
    try {
        startSocket();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the function that creates the socket.

```
    private void startSocket() throws URISyntaxException
{
    socket = IO.socket("http://localhost");
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() 
    {
      @Override
      public void call(Object... args) 
      {
        socket.emit("adduser", "");
      }
    }).on("chat_msg", new Emitter.Listener() 
    {
      @Override
      public void call(Object... args) 
      {
          JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)args[0];
          try {
            String uname = obj.getString("username");
            String msg = obj.getString("msg");
            updateList(uname, msg);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }).on("username", new Emitter.Listener() 
    {
          @Override
          public void call(Object... args) 
          {
              JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)args[0];
              try {
                username = obj.getString("username");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
    }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() 
    {
      @Override
      public void call(Object... args) 
      {

      }

    });
    socket.connect();
}
```

Now, I have a chat functionality, the chat messages go into a ListView with a customized adapter which I created, outside the socket function, like this.

```
class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Text>
{
     FancyAdapter()
     {
         super(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, texts);
     }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
     {
         ViewHolder holder;
         if(convertView == null)
         {
             LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
             convertView.setTag(holder);
         }
         else
         {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }
         holder.populateFrom(texts.get(position));
         return(convertView);
     }
}

class ViewHolder
{
     public TextView text_username = null;
     public TextView text_message = null;

     ViewHolder(View row)
     {
         text_username = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_username);
         text_message = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_message);
     }
     void populateFrom(Text w)
     {
         text_username.setText(w.username);
         text_message.setText(w.message);
     }
}

FancyAdapter adapter = null;

private void initList()
{
      adapter = new FancyAdapter();
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void updateList(String uname, String message)
{
    Text text = new Text();
    text.username = uname;
    text.message = message;
    texts.add(text); 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now, when I call updateList(string, string) from within a socket call, specifically "chat_message", I get "ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Oh well, I tried moving the list/adapter related functions and classes inside the EVENT_CONNECT event in the socket function, but it appears things defined in there won't get defined for the other events like "chat_message".

So I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interact with views only from UI Thread try this:

```
MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
          updateList(uname, msg);
      }
});
```